# How to run this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I have a 'friends' table, with two attributes: `(friend1,friend2)`, which represents a friendship between 'friend1' and 'friend2'.  for example, if the tuple `('John','Mike')` is in 'friends', then John is a friend of Mike and vice versa (consequently, the tuple `('Mike','John')` will NOT be in 'friends').
I'm looking for an sql query that will produce all of John's friends.
(Notice that John can either appear under 'friend1' or under 'friend2')
So at first I thought about the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM friends
WHERE friend1='John' OR friend2='John';
```

Let's label that as 'John's_friends', and now I can have something like:

```
SELECT friend1
FROM johns_friends
WHERE friends1<>'John'
UNION
SELECT friend2
FROM johns_friends
WHERE friends2<>'John';
```

Never mind the fact that I don't know how to properly run this particular query (the above will not 'compile' no matter how I tried aliasing), but I feel like there's much simpler way to do it, and I could really use some help in extracting the information I need from the 'friends' table.

EDIT:
To be more clear: I want a list - **one clumn** - of all john's friends.  hence the second query.

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve with that second query

Comment: I want a list, one column of all John's friends.

Comment: Do you have table with name `johns_friends`? 
And could you, pleas, explain what is the problem with the first query?

Comment: edited the main post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this

```
SELECT friend1 as johns_friends 
FROM friends 
WHERE friend2 = 'John'
UNION
SELECT friend2 as johns_friends 
FROM friends 
WHERE friend1 = 'John'
;
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT friend1
FROM friends
WHERE friend2 = 'John'
UNION
SELECT friend2
FROM friends
WHERE friend1 = 'John'
;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use one query:

```
SELECT friend1
FROM friends
WHERE friend2 = 'John'
UNION
SELECT friend2
FROM friends
WHERE friend1 = 'John';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get a result like:

```
|FRIEND|
--------
|Mike  |
--------
|Jack  |
--------
```

You could try

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`FRIEND`) AS `FRIEND` FROM (
    SELECT `friends1` AS `FRIEND` FROM `johns_friends` WHERE `friends1` <> 'John'
    UNION
    SELECT `friends2` AS `FRIEND` FROM `johns_friends` WHERE `friends2` <> 'John'
) AS `f`
```

SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30027/1